# ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add generates error "The syntax of this name isn't correct."

Tags: excel, vba

This code has been working, now it is giving me:

> Run-time error '1004'
>   The syntax of this name isn't correct.

[image]

I think after the script runs I need to remove this saved name, however, I do not know how to do this.

If after the debug error I start the code at the beginning of the with statement it works.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyList1", RefersTo:="=FlexInfo[Card Holder]"
'RefersTo:="=TableName[ColumnHeader]"

With Range("CardHold").Validation
     .Delete
     .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=MyList1" '<Errors here
     .ShowError = False
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the either

1. Name range (MyList1) already exists in the Excel workbook. Try deleting it before adding it again.
2. the space between Card & Holder in the another name range "*FlexInfo[Card Holder]*" is causing the issue.

---

```
On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("MyList1").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("FlexInfo[Card Holder]").Name = "FlexInfo[CardHolder]"
On Error GoTo 0

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyList1", RefersTo:="=FlexInfo[CardHolder]"
'RefersTo:="=TableName[ColumnHeader]"

With Range("CardHold").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=MyList1" '<Errors here
    .ShowError = False
End With
```

Comment: It was indeed that MyList1 was referenced somewhere it did not need to be, thanks for the help!